# JavaScript - Extract specific nodes along with the node start position

Tags: javascript

Following is a sample node,

```
<div>Hell<span class="locate">Q1</span>o <b>w<span class="locate">Q2</span>or</b>ld</div>
```

My goal is to `extract all the 'locate' class nodes along with their start character/text position` (So later, i can reuse that text/character position to inject the node)

**Ex**:

```
<div>Hell<span class="locate">Q1</span>o <b>w<span class="locate">Q2</span>or</b>ld</div>
```

Extract something like

Output:
**1. Extraction**

```
[
    {
        "start": 5,
        "node": "<span class='locate'>Q1</span>"
    },
    {
        "start": 9,
        "node": "<span class='locate'>Q2</span>"
    }
]
```

2. Removal of `locate` nodes to Hello **wor**ld`

**So far what I've tried**:
treeWalker = document.createTreeWalker(input, NodeFilter.SHOW_ALL);

```
while(treeWalker.nextNode()) {
    temp = {};
    currentNode = treeWalker.currentNode;
    if (currentNode.parentNode.tagName.toLowerCase() === 'div') {
        totalText += currentNode.textContent.length;
        if (
            currentNode.className &&
            currentNode.className.toLowerCase() === 'locate'
        ) {
            temp.startPosition = totalText;
            temp.node = currentNode.cloneNode(true);
            collectorArray.push(temp);
            console.log(currentNode, totalText);                               
        } else {
            updatedNode.appendChild(currentNode.cloneNode(true));
            console.log(currentNode, totalText);                               
        }
    }
}
```

I tried to use `TreeWalker` to collect nodes and start position, but, I'm not getting no where.

I also feel the way i calculate the `text` length is wrong. May be a better way?

The idea of the whole process is, reapply the collected `locate` nodes after some text change occurs, using the start position and node collected.

Comment: What is `start position`

Comment: character/text position.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this (sorry for bad indentation in the snippet):

```js
var nodeIterator = document.createNodeIterator(
  document.getElementById('someId'),

  NodeFilter.SHOW_ELEMENT,

    { acceptNode: function(node) {
      if ( node.className == 'locate' ) {
        return NodeFilter.FILTER_ACCEPT;
      }
    }
  },
  false
);


var node;
var doc = document.getElementById('someId').textContent;

var result = [];
var currentStart = 0;

while ((node = nodeIterator.nextNode())) {

  var tempDoc = doc.slice(currentStart, doc.length);
  var idx = tempDoc.indexOf(node.textContent);  
 var temp = {};  
  
 temp.start = currentStart + idx;
 temp.node = node.outerHTML;

 currentStart += (idx + node.textContent.length);

 result.push(temp);
    
}

console.log(result)
```

```html
<div id="someId">Hell<span class="locate">Q1</span>o <b>w<span class="locate">Q1</span>or</b>ld<span class="locate">Q1</span></div>
```

Note, that I use `SHOW_ELEMENT` because you distinguish what is needed by elements class name. So later you can just set a rule in iterator that accepts only those nodes.

And then I get `textContent` of the root element and get index value of accepted nodes from iterator object.

Comment: Thx. Its a nice solution, but, if both the "locate" has same text inside the `doc.indexOf` is fetching the first position for 2nd match.
Ex:
`<div>Hell<span class="locate">Q1</span>o <b>w<span class="locate">Q1</span>or</b>ld</div>`

Comment: I edited my post - cant say I tested it 100%, but seems it works well. The idea is to remove elements of  the root container by the last found index and then find the index of  the next item in that result. Comment please, if something goes wrong